# How to properly export from Cinema 4D to GLTF and use it with Three.JS?

Tags: javascript, three.js, cinema-4d, gltf

I have been trying to do this for a few weeks, Trying to find out how on my own, But I have failed over and over, With little progress.

So if anyone can help me, I will be very thankful.

In advance thank you.

Comment: Do you need to export a model or an animation ? If it's simply a model, you can export an .obj then [convert it] (https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/utils/converters/obj/convert_obj_three.py) to three.js

Comment: Just the model, Thanks, That works... But before you answered, I tried opening the model from Cinema 4D in Blender and using the three.js  exporting tool of blender, That worked too... And from now on I'm going to be using Blender only ;) Again, Thank you!

Comment: You could try exporting as OBJ or Alembic, load this in with three.js and then export with three.js as GLTFExporter. Then you could load the GLTF anytime.

Comment: Might be worth trying [Sketchfab's exporter](https://sketchfab.com/exporters/cinema4d). Once it's in Sketchfab you can mark it as "downloadable" and get a glTF version.

Comment: Exporter now in Maxon Labs: https://labs.maxon.net/?p=3360

Answer (score 3):

As of March 2019, Cinema4D now has an official (but experimental) glTF 2.0 exporter: https://labs.maxon.net/?p=3360